# What is the correct way to erase the last inserted element of a map without c++11?

Tags: c++, dictionary

The question is self-explanatory. But to complement suppose: `map<int,int>` with at least 10 inserted elements. What is the correct way to delete the last inserted element?

By the last element inserted I mean, not the last element of the map, but the element that I inserted the last time I inserted an element.

Comment: Do you mean the last element in he map or the element inserted (chronologically) last?

Comment: The last element inserted, as I've wrote in the question

Comment: And the ambigous way you wrote it in the question is exactly why I wrote that comment (and why *Cubic*'s and *Nicol*'s answers are so different).

Comment: You're right its very ambiguous, and worse, it still looks ambiguous

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Save an iterator to the last inserted element. The elements in the map are ordered by the key values, not by insertion order.

`map::insert` returns an iterator to the last inserted element (and a `bool` indicating if an insertion took place).

```
auto p = yourMap.insert(k,v);
if(p.second) {
    lastInsert = p.first;
} else {
    //Ambiguous. Depending on what you want
    //this could be an error, or you update the value and the iterator,
    //or you update just the value.
}
```

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert

Comment: Can you please write how do I save an iterator of the element I'm inserting?

Comment: @vinaoxd `std::map::insert` returns a `std::pair<iterator,bool>`, whose first element is an iterator to the newly inserted element (and whose second element says if something was inserted or the key was already present). So just say `newest = map.insert(...).first` everytime you insert something, and finally `map.erase(newest)`.

Comment: Thanks for the post edit but I'm not using `insert` to insert elements. The map is: `map<unsigned int,vector<myclass> >hold` i'm inserting it via: `hold[uPosition].push_back( myclassobject )` where `uPosition` is an `unsigned int` and `myclassobject` is a simple `myclass myclassobject;`

Comment: @vinaoxd Well, then you have a problem, since the `[]`-operator doesn't make a difference between updating and inserting, but of course you can manage the last inserted/updated element otherwise, by e.g. storing `uPosition` and then using the `erase` version that takes a key instead of an iterator.

Comment: @vinao Then you don't insert elements into the map, you insert elements into a collection thats in a map. You could use map::find to get the iterator, but if you're inserting and need an iterator at the same time (and want to make sure an element is actually inserted, not updated) you should use map::insert.

Comment: That brings up a good question, how to store into that map using `insert`? Sorry for the collection of questions, but knowledge is power!

Comment: @vinaoxd It seems you should have asked a bunch of different questions right from the start. Unorganized knowledge isn't much more power than no knowledge at all.

Comment: @vinaoxd You insert elements like I just showed you. If the insertion fails (the .second of the pair is false) then p.first will be an iterator to the element that's already there. Then you can update that value (in your case `(*p.first).push_back(object)`).

Comment: I guess you have something against my person Christian, there was no way I could have imagined all of this with my primary question, please consider that I'm studying, I'm not a professional making professional questions. I sincerely didn't understand the 'unorganized knowledge'. Should I rather have not asked and stood in doubt when it came up? Thanks a lot cubic I've learned quite a bit from your answers!

Comment: @vinao I don't think it was meant as a personal insult or anything the like. He probably just meant to say that you should look more into the documentation of std::map and more generally the way STL works.

Comment: @vinaoxd And you maybe should have made more clear what your actual intent is in the question. Because once you thought more thoroughly about what your code actually does when *inserting*, you might have gotten a clearer understanding of what the actual problem is you want to solve. Other than that asking follow up questions in comments instead of posting proper SO questions is rarely a good idea. But rest assured that I don't have anything against your person, *vinao* (until your above comment maybe, no, just kidding ;)).

Comment: Since the question explicitly says “without C++11”, the first line of the code sample should be `std::pair<yourMap_type::iterator, bool> p = yourMap.insert(std::pair<k_type, v_type>(k, v));`.

Answer (score 6):

There is no API function for doing that. If keeping track of the order you inserted the elements in is important, then you're going to have to have a `vector<map<...>::iterator>` of insertions, as well as keeping it up-to-date when you remove things from the `map`.

How exactly you do that depends on how your code is structured, where the `map` is, and what manages interactions with it.

Comment: Thank you, I could only remember of `std::prev( location.end() )`

Comment: This removes the last element from the map, not the last inserted element.

Comment: is --iterator safe ? I doubt whether its perfectly legal.

Comment: @ArunMu: As long as the map has elements, yes, --iterator is safe.

Comment: The doubt about `--iterator` might come from implementations using pointers as iterators for `std::vector`. In that case you are not allowed to decrement the temporary returned by the function. And the compiler will tell you so.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Was just confirming coz I have read somewhere "C++ language doesn't allow you to modify temporaries of builtin type.".If the implementation of the iterator turns out to be a normal pointer, wont the above statement matter ?